# Why won't this ajax counter display?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to display how many people are actually online at my website.  The ajax code however isn't displaying anything in my div and I am not sure why this is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  //START After 5 minutes update database timestamp (this part of script works)
  fnShowImOnline();
  setInterval('fnShowImOnline', 120000);

  function fnShowImOnline() {
    $.get('counter_im_online.php');
  }
  //END 
  {
  $.ajax({url: 'counter_members_online.php', dataType: 'json', success: function(response) {
    if (isNumeric(response.total)) {
      $('#OnlineTotal').html(response.total + " Total ");
      $('#OnlineNow').html(response.online +  " Online Now");
    }
  }
});
</script>

<div id="OnlineTotal"></div><div id="OnlineNow"></div>

<?php 
// Contents of counter_members_online.php:
// Members online.
$online_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users where last_checked_in > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)";
$online_RS  = mysql_query($online_sql);
$online_row = mysql_fetch_row($online_RS);
$online     = $online_row[0];

// Members total.
$total_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
$total_RS  = mysql_query($total_sql);
$total_row = mysql_fetch_row($total_RS);
$total     = $total_row[0];
$response  = json_encode(array('total'=>$total,'online'=>$online));
echo($response);
?>
```

Comment: I d suggest you analyze http traffic with firebug. Then post back the results, that will be useful to discard which side (server or client) is producing the error.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't this code

```
$.ajax({url: 'counter_members_online.php', dataType: 'json', success: function(response) {
        if (isNumeric(response.total)) {
            $('#OnlineTotal').html(response.total + " Total ");
            $('#OnlineNow').html(response.online +  " Online Now");
        }
    }
});
```

be the part of `function fnShowImOnline()`

i.e. `function fnShowImOnline` should read

```
function fnShowImOnline() {
$.ajax({url: 'counter_members_online.php', dataType: 'json', success: function(response) {
        if (isNumeric(response.total)) {
            $('#OnlineTotal').html(response.total + " Total ");
            $('#OnlineNow').html(response.online +  " Online Now");
        }
    }
});
}
```

can you try replacing your  tag with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  //START After 5 minutes update database timestamp (this part of script works)
  fnShowImOnline();
  setInterval('fnShowImOnline', 120000);
});

    function fnShowImOnline() {
    $.ajax({url: 'counter_members_online.php', dataType: 'json', success: function(response) {
            if (isNumeric(response.total)) {
                $('#OnlineTotal').html(response.total + " Total ");
                $('#OnlineNow').html(response.online +  " Online Now");
            }
        }
    });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I tried removing } // END { so that it would be part of that function, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: try doing a console.log(response); just before isNumeric() line and see the response in firefox/chrome , and then let us know what you see there

Comment: Okay if I hit f12 I get: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):143
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input (index):1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: I just edited my answer for all of your script tag, can you check it , modify your code accordingly and then let me know what you see

Comment: It doesn't work.  I also tried it with the console.log(response); which didn't give me any errors this time but it still doesn't show online count.

Comment: what is the response it is showing for console.log(response);

Comment: The console log was empty.

Comment: and your SQL queries are running fine ? meaning are they returning any data?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problems.  The below script works now, the $.ajax part had a } before it and it wasn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  // After 5 minutes update database timestamp (this part of script works)
  fnShowImOnline();
  setInterval('fnShowImOnline', 120000);
});

    function fnShowImOnline() {
    $.get('counter_im_online.php');
    }

$.ajax({
    url: 'counter_members_online.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        if (!isNaN(response.total)) {
            $('#OnlineTotal').html(response.total + " Total ");
            $('#OnlineOnline').html(response.online +  " Members Online");
        }
    }
})
</script>
```